# AWS security alert in google play

Tags: android, android-intent, amazon-web-services

I have this issue on my app on google play. please help me to solve this issue

> Security alert
>   Your Amazon Web  Services credentials may be exposed. This exposure of your credentials  could lead to unauthorised access to your AWS account, which may include associated excessive charges, and potentially unauthorised access to  your data and your users' data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty straightforward, really... It sounds like you have embedded your AWS credentials in your app, where they can be reverse-engineered and compromised.  You can't just call AWS services with your IAM credentials coded into the code that you distribute.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.May i know what is the best way should implement this

Comment: @Michael Can you suggest the best way?

Comment: @hriziya [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) privides several capabilities, including a mechanism that your app can use to obtain temporary credentials for accessing other AWS services.